# Default slot inside Vue3 Component is not rendered in unit test using Vue Test Utils

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, vuejs3, vue-test-utils, vitest

I'm using Vue3 and Vue Test Utils in my unit tests and was successfully until arrived to this component with two slots inside, a default and a title (it's a copy and paste from the UIDisclosure example from Headless UI):

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { Disclosure, DisclosureButton, DisclosurePanel } from '@headlessui/vue'

const props = withDefaults(defineProps<{ title?: string }>(), { title: '' })
</script>

<template>
  <div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
    <div class="mx-auto w-full rounded-2xl p-2">
      <Disclosure v-slot="{ open }">
        <DisclosureButton
          class="textpurple-900 flex w-full justify-between rounded-lg bg-purple-100 px-4 py-2 text-left text-sm font-medium hover:bg-purple-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-purple-500 focus-visible:ring-opacity-75"
        >
          <span data-test="title">
            <slot name="title">{{ props.title }}</slot>
          </span>
          <div :class="open && 'rotate-90 transform'">></div>
        </DisclosureButton>
        <DisclosurePanel class="textsm px-4 pb-2 pt-4 text-gray-500">
          <!-- This is the default slot. -->
          <span data-test="panel">
            <slot />
          </span>
        </DisclosurePanel>
      </Disclosure>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

I'm trying to test it out with those specs:

```
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import { mount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import UIDisclosure from '../UIDisclosure.vue'

const panelSelector = '[data-test="panel"]'
const titleSelector = '[data-test="title"]'

describe('test the disclosure', () => {
  describe('renders properly', async () => {
    it('passing title as prop', () => {
      const title = 'This is an example title'
      const wrapper = mount(UIDisclosure, {
        props: {
          title
        }
      })

      const content = wrapper.find(titleSelector).text()
      expect(content).toBe(title)
    })

    it('passing title as slot', () => {
      const title = 'This is a slot title'
      const wrapper = mount(UIDisclosure, {
        slots: {
          title: `<span id="slotTitle">${title}</span>`
        }
      })

      const titleContent = wrapper.find(titleSelector)
      expect(titleContent.html()).toContain(title)
      const panelContent = wrapper.findAll(panelSelector)
      expect(panelContent).toHaveLength(0)
    })

    it('using the default panel slot', () => {
      const panel = 'The content of the panel'
      const wrapper = mount(UIDisclosure, {
        slots: {
          default: `<span id="slotTitle">${panel}</span>`
        }
      })

      const titleContent = wrapper.find(titleSelector)
      expect(titleContent.text()).toBe('')
      const panelContent = wrapper.find(panelSelector)
      expect(panelContent.text()).toContain(panel)
    })
  })
})
```

In the last one, the default slot is always empty and the html output from `wrapper.html()` is:

```
<div class="flex flex-row flex-wrap">
  <div class="mx-auto w-full rounded-2xl p-2"><button id="headlessui-disclosure-button-5" type="button" aria-expanded="false" data-headlessui-state="" class="textpurple-900 flex w-full justify-between rounded-lg bg-purple-100 px-4 py-2 text-left text-sm font-medium hover:bg-purple-200 focus:outline-none focus-visible:ring focus-visible:ring-purple-500 focus-visible:ring-opacity-75"><span data-test="title"></span>
      <div class="">&gt;</div>
    </button>
    <!---->
  </div>
</div>
```

What I'm doing wrong? I know that in the official doc of Vue Testing Utils they are using only wrapper.html().contains() examples, but I want to test the specific slot content since I have many slots with specific means. I'm thinking wrong? Should I don't care about many slots?

In this specific situation, the Disclosure from Headless UI has a title that could be different from the panel and I want to unit test that they should be different each other and ...

Answer (score 0):

There is no problem with default slot. The problem is that `DisclosurePanel` is not rendered, as you can see in `wrapper.html()` there is no `<span data-test="panel">`. You need to set `Disclosure` to opened state, wait for tick and then check html.